# Bash scripting question. Potential Error with Testcase?

Tags: bash

I am given a logfile containing live trading logs. Now I need to aggregate the symbols we trade along with the number of trades for that symbol in decreasing order of the number of trades. Please note that each line corresponds to a single trade.

My Input - I have the logs in the following format:

```
Datetime(YYYYMMDDHHMMSS), Stock, Symbol, BUY/SELL, Quantity, Price
20190102091055,IBM,BUY,1.160
20190102091058,BABA,SELL,10,155
20190102091059,IBM,BUY,2,159
```

Expected Output:

```
IBM 2
BABA 1
```

This is the code I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A symbols  # Declare an associative array to store the symbols and their counts

# Read input line by line
while read line
do
  # Extract the stock symbol from the line
  symbol=$(echo "$line" | cut -d',' -f2)

  # If the symbol already exists in the array, increment its count
  # Otherwise, add the symbol to the array with a count of 1
  if [[ ${symbols[$symbol]+_} ]]; then
    symbols[$symbol]=$((symbols[$symbol]+1))
  else
    symbols[$symbol]=1
  fi
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}" # Read input from stdin or from a file specified as a command-line argument

# Sort the symbols and their counts in descending order of count
for symbol in "${!symbols[@]}"
do
  echo "$symbol ${symbols[$symbol]}"
done | sort -rnk2
```

Error we received:

Error code:

Input (stdin)

```
20190527200918,AMZN,SELL,32,1830
20190527200918,AMZN,BUY,26,1827
20190527200918,IBM,SELL,12,139
20190527200918,IBM,SELL,93,144
20190527200918,IBM,SELL,6,141
20190527200918,AMZN,BUY,44,1833
20190527200918,GOOG,SELL,77,1145
20190527200918,GOOG,BUY,89,1135
20190527200918,IBM,BUY,21,139
20190527200918,AMZN,BUY,89,1834
20190527200918,IBM,SELL,80,139
20190527200918,MSFT,SELL,48,135
20190527200918,MSFT,BUY,66,131
20190527200918,MSFT,SELL,21,141
20190527200918,AMZN,SELL,5,1826
20190527200918,MSFT,BUY,47,141
20190527200918,AMZN,SELL,19,1833
20190527200918,AMZN,BUY,22,1831
20190527200918,IBM,BUY,75,139
20190527200918,GOOG,BUY,70,1141
20190527200918,AAPL,SELL,43,182
20190527200918,MSFT,BUY,7,136
20190527200918,GOOG,SELL,89,1147
20190527200918,AMZN,SELL,54,1828
20190527200918,AAPL,SELL,7,189
20190527200918,MSFT,SELL,66,136
20190527200918,AAPL,SELL,31,189
20190527200918,IBM,BUY,39,137
20190527200918,MSFT,SELL,10,128
20190527200918,IBM,BUY,15,146
20190527200918,IBM,SELL,38,133
20190527200918,IBM,SELL,76,146
20190527200918,G{-truncated-}
```

Your Output (stdout)

```
IBM 26
MSFT 22
AMZN 21
GOOG 17
AAPL 13
```

Expected Output

```
IBM 27
MSFT 22
AMZN 21
GOOG 17
AAPL 13
```

Comment: Try running your script with `bash -x` in front of it and see if you can see any issues in the way things are getting calculated.

Answer (score 1):

A possible explanation for *Your Output* differing from the *Expected Output* by one trade for one symbol is that that symbol trade is on the last input line and that line is not terminated by the ending delimiter *newline*. This error could be eluded by testing the assigned line rather than the exit status of `read`, i. e. by changing `while read line` to `while read line; [ "$line" ]`.

Answer (score 1):

As Armali suggests, a broken record will do this.

```
$: head -9 file | wc
      9      14     314
$: head -9 file | ./tst # listed below (after adding fix suggested below)
IBM 5
AMZN 2
BABA 1

$: head -c 310 file | wc    # knocks off last 4 bytes
      8      14     310
$: head -c 310 file | ./tst # loses broken record
IBM 4
AMZN 2
BABA 1
```

c.f. [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - you might try

```
while IFS=, read -a _ symbol - || [[ -n "$symbol" ]]
```

which checks the target var and processes if it got a value. With that added, the outputs will be the same.

`awk` will be a lot faster, though, makes it easy to skip the header, and won't choke on that broken record.

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{sym[$2]++}END{for(k in sym)printf "%s %s\n",k,sym[k]}' "$1" | sort -k2nr
IBM 12
AMZN 8
MSFT 7
GOOG 4
AAPL 3
BABA 1

$: head -9 file | awk -F, 'NR>1{ sym[$2]++; } END { for(k in sym) printf "%s %s\n", k, sym[k]}' | sort -k2nr
IBM 5
AMZN 2
BABA 1

$: head -c 310 file | awk -F, 'NR>1{ sym[$2]++; } END { for(k in sym) printf "%s %s\n", k, sym[k]}' | sort -k2nr
IBM 5
AMZN 2
BABA 1
```

`printf` also gives you a LOT of formatting options, if (for example) you'd rather use a tab, or set the fields to justified fixed widths. We could write a sort in the `awk` as well, but `sort` is pretty well optimized, and this is less work. YMMV.

My input -

```
$: cat file
Datetime(YYYYMMDDHHMMSS), Stock, Symbol, BUY/SELL, Quantity, Price
20190102091055,IBM,BUY,1,160
20190102091058,BABA,SELL,10,155
20190102091059,IBM,BUY,2,159
20190527200918,AMZN,SELL,32,1830
20190527200918,AMZN,BUY,26,1827
20190527200918,IBM,SELL,12,139
20190527200918,IBM,SELL,93,144
20190527200918,IBM,SELL,6,141
20190527200918,AMZN,BUY,44,1833
20190527200918,GOOG,SELL,77,1145
20190527200918,GOOG,BUY,89,1135
20190527200918,IBM,BUY,21,139
20190527200918,AMZN,BUY,89,1834
20190527200918,IBM,SELL,80,139
20190527200918,MSFT,SELL,48,135
20190527200918,MSFT,BUY,66,131
20190527200918,MSFT,SELL,21,141
20190527200918,AMZN,SELL,5,1826
20190527200918,MSFT,BUY,47,141
20190527200918,AMZN,SELL,19,1833
20190527200918,AMZN,BUY,22,1831
20190527200918,IBM,BUY,75,139
20190527200918,GOOG,BUY,70,1141
20190527200918,AAPL,SELL,43,182
20190527200918,MSFT,BUY,7,136
20190527200918,GOOG,SELL,89,1147
20190527200918,AMZN,SELL,54,1828
20190527200918,AAPL,SELL,7,189
20190527200918,MSFT,SELL,66,136
20190527200918,AAPL,SELL,31,189
20190527200918,IBM,BUY,39,137
20190527200918,MSFT,SELL,10,128
20190527200918,IBM,BUY,15,146
20190527200918,IBM,SELL,38,133
20190527200918,IBM,SELL,76,146
```

If you just really want it in native `bash` -

```
$: cat tst
#!/bin/bash
declare -A cnt=() # associative array for symbols counts

while IFS=, read _ sym _ || [[ -n "$sym" ]]     # allows for broken last record
do [[ "${sym:0:1}" == ' ' ]] || ((cnt[$sym]++)) # skips the header
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"

for sym in "${!cnt[@]}"; do echo "$sym ${cnt[$sym]}"; done | sort -rnk2

$: ./tst file
IBM 12
AMZN 8
MSFT 7
GOOG 4
AAPL 3
BABA 1
```

Just for comparison, I copy/pasted the non-header data in the above file over and over to make it big enough for time tests to be informative.

```
$: ls -l file
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 454071699 Mar  9 09:52 file
```

Using `awk`:

```
$: time { awk -F, 'NR>1{ sym[$2]++; } END { for(k in sym) printf "%s %s\n", k, sym[k]}' file | sort -k2nr; }
IBM 4958016
AMZN 3305344
MSFT 2892176
GOOG 1652672
AAPL 1239504
BABA 413168

real    0m4.179s
user    0m3.905s
sys     0m0.341s
```

Using M. Nejat Aydin's pipeline:

```
$: time { cut -d, -f2 file | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr; }
4958016 IBM
3305344 AMZN
2892176 MSFT
1652672 GOOG
1239504 AAPL
 413168 BABA
      1  Stock

real    0m13.070s
user    0m14.623s
sys     0m1.512s
```

Using my version of your `bash` as listed above:

```
$: time ./tst file
IBM 4958016
AMZN 3305344
MSFT 2892176
GOOG 1652672
AAPL 1239504
BABA 413168

real    21m35.327s
user    6m16.405s
sys     15m11.232s
```

You can see that on a file of any size, the performance difference is *significant*.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use pure `bash` for this task; it's slow. This one liner should do the trick much faster:

```
cut -d, -f2 file | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

or, using `awk`

```
awk -F, '{++c[$2]} END{for (i in c) print i,c[i]}' file | sort -k2nr
```

Comment: This doesn't match the requested format, or handle the header(though OP doesn't skip the header either...) - generally seems a good base approach though.